# Sortable with Bootstrap and 2 row fluid columns

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

I am actually coding a kind dashboard page with some widgets i'd like to be sortable. The main structure of the page is based on Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.
The interesting part is as follow :

```
    <div class="row fluid">
    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <div class="span6 sortable">
        <div class="span12">
            Widget 1
        </div>

        <div class="span12">
            Widget 2
        </div>

        <div class="span12">
            Widget 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <div class="span6 sortable">
        <div class="span12">
            Widget 4
        </div>

        <div class="span12">
            Widget 5
        </div>

        <div class="span12">
            Widget 6
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And the JS code like :

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable();
$( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

My problem is that I can sort the widget in the same column, but I can't do the sorting from one column to another.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use *connectWith* parameter. Check out this example: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

So this is what you need:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({connectWith: ".sortable"}).disableSelection();
```

Here's a working jsFiddle for your particular case: http://jsfiddle.net/SvxGb/